# OpenVPN клиент не подключается к серверу

Tags: openvpn

OpenVPN клиент не подключается к серверу, что не так?

На сервере Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (x86_64)

**сервер конфиг:**

```
local *.*.*.* #my server ip
port 443
# TCP or UDP server?
proto tcp
dev tun0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 192.168.14.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.35.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.14.0 255.255.255.252
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
keepalive 10 120
tls-server
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
tls-timeout 120
cipher AES-256-CBC   # AES
auth SHA512
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 9
mute 20
```

**клиент конфиг:**

```
client
remote *.*.*.* 443 tcp # Адрес и порт OpenVPN сервера
proto udp # Протокол, должен совпадать с сервером
dev tun # Устройство
# Сертификаты и ключи
ca ca.crt
dh dh2048.pem
cert client2.crt
key client2.key
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC #Алгоритм шифрования, должен совпадать с серверным
auth SHA512 
verb 6
mute 20
keepalive 10 120
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
```

лог клиента:

```
2015-12-22 17:42:08 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015, LZO 2.08
2015-12-22 17:42:09 *Tunnelblick: Established communication with OpenVPN
2015-12-22 17:42:09 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
2015-12-22 17:42:09 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2015-12-22 17:42:09 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
2015-12-22 17:42:09 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:443 [nonblock]
2015-12-22 17:42:10 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:443
2015-12-22 17:42:10 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
2015-12-22 17:42:10 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:443
2015-12-22 17:42:11 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
2015-12-22 17:42:11 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
2015-12-22 17:42:11 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
2015-12-22 17:42:11 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2015-12-22 17:42:11 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
2015-12-22 17:42:11 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:443 [nonblock]
2015-12-22 17:42:12 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:443
2015-12-22 17:42:12 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
2015-12-22 17:42:12 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:443
2015-12-22 17:42:14 Connection reset, restarting [-1]
2015-12-22 17:42:14 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
2015-12-22 17:42:14 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
2015-12-22 17:42:14 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2015-12-22 17:42:14 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
2015-12-22 17:42:14 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:443 [nonblock]
2015-12-22 17:42:15 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:443
2015-12-22 17:42:15 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: [undef]
2015-12-22 17:42:15 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:443
2015-12-22 17:42:15 *Tunnelblick: Disconnecting; VPN Details… window disconnect button pressed
2015-12-22 17:42:15 *Tunnelblick: Disconnecting using 'kill'
2015-12-22 17:42:15 event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
2015-12-22 17:42:15 SIGTERM[hard,] received, process exiting
2015-12-22 17:42:17 *Tunnelblick: No 'post-disconnect.sh' script to execute
2015-12-22 17:42:17 *Tunnelblick: Expected disconnection occurred.
```

Comment: *proto udp # Протокол, должен совпадать с сервером* — у вас прямо в комментариях написана подсказка

Comment: 443 порт случаем апач или нгинкс не занимает?

Answer (score 2):

Определитесь с используемым протоколом
Либо

```
proto tcp
```

либо

```
proto udp
```

На сервере и клиенте он должен совпадать.

и уберите **tcp** из строчки

```
remote *.*.*.* 443 tcp
```

Comment: Изменил но все еще не соединяется

`client
remote *.*.*.* 443 
proto tcp`

Comment: А что в логах сервера пишется? попробуй поменять SHA512 на SHA256. Смущает запись  WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.

Comment: а со стороны провайдера может заблокироваться openvpn (udp, tcp) порт ? просто раньше у меня в другом сервере работал а теперь там тоже не работает...

Answer (score 0):

И у меня проблема! Не хочет подключаться.

Суть в том, что на своем компе есть `VMWare Workstation` и в нем сервер `CentOS 6.7` с развернутым в нем `OpenVPN`.

При коннекте через клиента выдает такой лог:

```
Fri Apr 08 11:19:45 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.10 i686-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Mar 10 2016

Fri Apr 08 11:19:45 2016 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater)

Fri Apr 08 11:19:45 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1s  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.09

Fri Apr 08 11:19:45 2016 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340

Fri Apr 08 11:19:45 2016 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...

Fri Apr 08 11:19:46 2016 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340

Fri Apr 08 11:19:46 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'

Fri Apr 08 11:19:46 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'

Fri Apr 08 11:19:46 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'

Fri Apr 08 11:19:46 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'

Fri Apr 08 11:19:46 2016 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]

Fri Apr 08 11:19:46 2016 UDPv4 link local: [undef]

Fri Apr 08 11:19:46 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]192.168.150.100:1194

Fri Apr 08 11:19:46 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1460103586,WAIT,,,
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы.